# Sorting an NSArray first by a specific NSString and AFTERWARDS by alphabetic order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting

currently I'm sorting my NSArray in alphabetic order like this:

```
NSArray *tempArr = [dictionaryFinishedProjects keysSortedByValueWithOptions:0 usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) 
{
   BOOL firstImportant = [obj1 hasPrefix:@"!"];
   BOOL secondImportant = [obj2 hasPrefix:@"!"];
   if(firstImportant && !secondImportant) 
   return 
   NSOrderedAscending;
   if(secondImportant && !firstImportant) 
   return 
   NSOrderedDescending;
   return 
   [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare:obj2];
 }];
```

The problem I'm having now, is that I need an additional order too. I want to show first all entries that have the string `@"firstEntry` and THEN the order I showed you in above code. What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: I created a class called HMFTableViewOrganizer that might help or give you an idea. https://github.com/Hackmodford/HMFTableViewOrganizer

Comment: Did you add a check for `firstEntry` to your current algorithm? Did it not work?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data with the the desired result after sorting?

Comment: There are three results in NSOrdering.  Ascending, Descending and NSOrderedSame.  Check the first string for ordering.  If they are the same then check the second string for ordering and return Ascending/Descending/Same from that compare.

Comment: Thanks! I will have a look into HMFTTableViewOrganizer. This sounds about right. I need to test it out another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can create method/s in your custom class, if you have one, and you can use `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` method or you can create block/s with different sorted option and just pass it to `sortedArrayUsingComparator:` method like that:

```
id sort1 = ^(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2){
    return [obj1 compare:obj2];
};


NSArray *tempArr = [[array allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:sort1];
```